# Traffic monitoring - NAT

Tags: networking, web, nat

Is there a good way to pick up the upload/download on my openbsd nat ?

I would like to create a small device that always show me if people on the network in uploading crazy or downloading ?

I've saw there is informatins in /proc/dev ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) to monitor the upload/download bandwidt on your OpenBSD NAT box. You can also use iptables to report to file when the traffic to specific IP is above the your set threshold. Once you have log data in file it will be easy to perform notifications based on it.

Comment: I've tried iptraf, not bad at all. Thanks for the idea.
My nat is now on a openBSD machine, I will try to grab some data with the iptables :). Thanks.